# Which is the best web server use for IoT device?

Tags: web-services

I use a device running Debian (https://armadillo.atmark-techno.com/armadillo-iot-g3) and want to use it as a web server. There are many web servers today. Which web server should I choose?

Comment: Welcome to IoT, Owl City!   We'll probably need a few more details to answer this question:  what IoT device are you planning on using, and for what application?

Comment: Welcome, @Owl. As anonymous2 indicates, your current question is a little too broad to be answered as it is. Can you please [edit] to explain what your goal is, what your constraints are and which servers you've considered so far to help us give you specific advice? I've put your question on hold temporarily while you edit; just reply when you've edited and we can reopen this.

Comment: @anonymous2 Thank you for reply.
I plan to use this device: https://armadillo.atmark-techno.com/armadillo-iot-g3.
I think there are many web servers supporting IoT devices. But I do not know which one to choose.

Comment: @Owl Ultimately, your choice won't matter too much unless you have specific requirements. Are you building a static site, or wanting to run something like PHP or Python on it? What is your website going to do?

Comment: I plan to build a dynamic web server, using server-side CGI like C. This device reads data from external modules and displays them on the web.